# How to change the size of the Eclipse GUI elements (window/tab borders and buttons size)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-cdt

The default Eclipse GUI (Indigo) is defined such that the graphic elements are pretty big. This means that the tabs and window borders, as well as the various buttons, take a considerable percentage of the Eclipse window real-estate area.

I normally work on an 1920x1200 monitor so it is not a big deal, but recently I had to present some work using a standard projector. C/C++ perspective was hard enough, but Debug perspective was unmanageable! There was almost no space for the actual contents as the screen was full with the GUI elements. I had to constantly change the tabs size to have some space in the view I wanted to examine.

How can I control the size of these GUI elements to reduce them to minimum?

*[question also posted in the eclipse community forum but I find SE to be more efficient]*